# How do I display loading on top of all elements when URL in fetch is changed in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the code that fetches json data from a URL, and displays it, like so:

```
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(url);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here instead of a catch() block
        // so that we don't swallow exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [url, setUrl]);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <LoadingAnimation />;
  } else {
    return <BasicLayout items={items} setUrl={setUrl} />;
  }
```

Where `url` is just an arbitrary url that fetches me some data. I have a custom `LoadingAnimation` function that simply displays loading when the page has not loaded. I pass `setUrl` down in the BasicLayout function because I want to change the URL parameters with the click of a button and update the data and display it. When the setUrl is triggered, the data updates as it should, with a 4-5 second delay. Now what additionally, while the data is updating during that 4-5 second delay, I want to display a different loading animation *on top of all the elements* and make the user unable to click on anything while the fetch is updating.

I have tried passing `setIsLoaded` into `BasicLayout` but that just replaced the entire screen and re-rendered every component. I especially don't want to re-render anything; just render the loading icon and hide it when everything has finished updating. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at this moment, in your component, `if` statements `return` what React have to render. So you got few ways:

in this example if `error` change React will show **BasicLayout** or **Error message** but if `isLoaded` will change, **LoadingAnimation** will be hide/shown under the previous element.

```
  useEffect(() => {
...
  }, [url, setUrl]);

return (
<>
 {error ? <div>Error: {error.message}</div> : <BasicLayout items={items} setUrl={setUrl} />}
 {!isLoaded && <LoadingAnimation />}
</>
)
```

If you'll use right css styles you can simply make **LoadingAnimation** a modal(pop-up) but for modals, as for me, better to use [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

index.html

```
<div id='root' ></div>
<div id='modal' ></div>
```

Portal.jsx

```
const Portal = ({children}) => {
const portalNode = document.getElementById('modal')
  return createPortal(children, portalNode)
}
```

Modal.jsx

```
const Modal = ({isActive, setIsActive, children}) => {
return (
<Portal>
{isActive && <div>{/* ...some code with children */}</div>}
</Portal>
)
}
```

So in your component it'll be something like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
...
  }, [url, setUrl]);

return (
<>
{error ? 
<div>Error: {error.message}</div>
 : 
<BasicLayout items={items} setUrl={setUrl} />}
<Modal isActive={!isLoaded} ><LoadingAnimation /></Modal>
</>
)
```

and you can make error component modal too.

hope, it'll help:))

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this actually looks like a nice approach, I wanted to follow a more simpler one but this is definitely a start, thank you so much!